# django: admin notifications,display if superuser

Tags: python, django

I am having a bit of a problems that would like some help with

I am using [django-admin-notifications](https://github.com/andybak/django-admin-notifications/) to display my notifications in my admin panel and I would like it to display when the user is a super user

Here is my code in admin.py:

```
def get_user_perm(request): 
    if not request.user.is_superuser:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def notification():
    if get_user_perm:

        return "Working"
    else:
        return "Still working"
admin_notifications.register(notification)
```

It still says `True` or displays "Working" regardless of the user

I am stuck and I don't know what to do, a bit of help will be appreciated, many thanks.

**UPDATE**

Tried printing the value

```
print get_user_perm
```

it says `(function user_perm at 0x00000000033384A8)`

Tried adding the `request`:

```
def notification(request):
    if get_user_perm(request):

        return "Working"
    else:
        return "Still working"
admin_notifications.register(notification)
```

but it says `notification() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`

Comment: yes because you're printing the function without calling it. you should be doing `print get_user_perm(request)` with a valid request object in the parentheses though

Comment: Yes, I have searched around and that should be the case but adding the request gives me an error and I don't know where to go from there

Answer (score 0):

Try to add brackets:

`get_user_perm()`